# Issues assigning a string to a linked list in Ada

Tags: pointers, for-loop, linked-list, ada

I'm trying to bring in a string and assign it , character by character, to a linked list, declared like so:

```
type lstring is private;
type lstring_node;
type lstring_access is access lstring_node;
type lstring_node is
    record
        Char : character;
        Position : integer;
        Next : lstring_access;
    end record;

private
   type lstring is 
      record
          First : lstring_access := null;
      end record;
```

The function to assign it goes like so:

```
function toLstring (Input : string) return lstring is
    LStr : lstring;
    Current : lstring_access;
begin
    -- Set the first item of LStr as Current.
    -- LStr will from now on inherit the items of Current.
    LStr.First := new lstring_node;
    Current := LStr.First;

    -- Iterate through the string and add it to the lstring.
    for I in 1..Input'Length loop
        if I /= 1 then
            Current := new lstring_node;
        end if;
        Current.Char := Input(I);
        Ada.Text_IO.Put(Current.Char);
        Current.Position := I;
        Current := Current.Next;
    end loop;

    -- Return the new lstring.  
    return LStr;
end toLstring;
```

I know through debugging that the for loop is working just fine, and the elements are being assigned to Current just fine. But for some reason the items aren't being added to LStr. Do I need to declare something after the for loop to finish it up? I'm under the impression that because Current is assigned to LStr.First, LStr would inherit the rest of the appended list. Am I wrong there?

Thanks

Comment: Just as an aside, this has got to be the most appalling custom string type I have ever encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the loop, you assign `Current.Next` (which is null at this point) to `Current`. This is a value copy. Changing the value of `Current` in the next iteration will not change the value of `Next` in the previous node. (Mind that `Current.Char` and `Current.Next` are implicit dereferences that will actually do `Current.all.Char` / `Next`, but `Current := new lstring_node` is not a dereference, because it changes the value of the reference.)

Instead, you should assign `new lstring_node` to `Next` and then advance your `Current` reference:

```
for I in Input'Range loop
    Current.Char := Input(I);
    Ada.Text_IO.Put(Current.Char);
    Current.Position := I - Input'First + 1;
    if I /= Input'Last then
        Current.Next := new lstring_node;
        Current := Current.Next;
    end if;
end loop;
```

Note that I changed the loop range (Strings are not required to start at 1) and tweaked the position calculation so you'll end up with a 1-based position index in your list.

Comment: Ah thank you! Works perfectly. Didn't think about it that way.